# Viewing allitems.aspx returns page not found error message

Tags: list

I have a list called Invoices in sharepoint. I created it long time ago and when I tried accessing it just today it returned this error message "page not found". I still can view the settings and the form but not the page allitems.aspx 
I have tried deleting the list using power shell but I recieved this error

> Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s):
>   "< nativehr>0x80070005
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $list.delete()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], Metho
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException

I have used the following command to delete it in power shell

```
$web = get-spweb http://sharepointsite 
$list = $web.lists["invoices"]
$list.delete()
```

when I removed the list, and then created a new one with the same name it still returns the same error page not found.

How do I fix this?? I want to access my list or create another one with the same name. I'm using SP2013.

Comment: Could you add the URL it's trying to reach? Could you also pull down the URLs the views should be?

Comment: @ChristoffeldeGruyter the url is http://sharepointsite/lists/listname/allitems.aspx

Comment: Did you check the ULS logs? Please check the logs and see what you get there.

Comment: If you see the list settings page, why not delete the list from there instead of using PowerShell? If there is no "Delete list" option, then see Hardik's answer regarding the "AllowDeletion" members of the SPList class.
Also, from the list settings you should be able to create a new view and then try to delete the "corrupt" AllItems.aspx view (maybe via SPD if not working via browser).

Comment: @MihailPopa I did that, same issue happened again when I tried to create a list with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the list created using a template? Try editing your view via list settings so only title/name column remains. This is to narrow down your problem and see whether it's related to a columns, in particular a lookup column.

I run into a similar problem after restoring a list using the PNP provisioning framework and the lookup columns where pointing to the source site.

If the page works after removing the columns, try to include columns one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: I have noticed anything with the name `Invoice` gets this error message... whether its a list name or even a view name in another list. for example if i have a list called `whatever` and I create a view called `invoice`. it'd give me not found error. what does this mean?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure but it sounds like a custom component that reacts to a view or list title. You could find out what is causing the not found error using the developer tool of you browser (chrome has a nice way of showing the network traffic, press 12 in chrome and check the network tab) or use fiddler to capture all traffic. This will probably give you an idea of what item/page is not found.

Comment: I had URL rewrite rule to direct any page contains voice, silly stupid me... that's why it was giving me page not found error. but as your suggestion, I've used google chrome and it guided me to solve this silly issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**`0x80070005` means access denied**...Make sure the account which is running powershell have the right permission on the site collection...also try to run the powershell console as Adminsitrator.

Sometimes, when you provision a list instance with Visual Studio, the provisioning could fail if there were errors in the script. Then you got a corrupted list. This could happen during the migration process as well. It is hard to be removed from SharePoint user interface or SharePoint designer.

You can delete it with following PowerShell script.

```
$web = get-spweb -Identity http://sharepointsite
$list = $web.lists["invoices"]
$list.AllowDeletion = $true
$list.Update()
$list.Delete()
```

In the above script, It is mentioned that you have to use `AllowDeletion` command first to set its flag to `true` as it will automatically `false` when list is corrupted.

Comment: on executing the command `$list.update()` it throws an error exactly like the above...

Comment: Updated my answer..Please look into it.

Comment: Is above information helps you?